# Russian WikiWords in FosWiki

Tags: locale, foswiki, cyrillic

I'm trying to set up support for the Russian language wiki. It turns out 
nothing. Russian language appears in the texts, but can't configure 
WikiWords.

When LocaleRegexes=1, UseLocale=1, Site Locale = ru_RU.utf8 Russian 
words are not recognized as the WikiWords. If LocaleRegexes=0 and filled 
UpperNational and LowerNational all the Russian words are recognized as 
a valid WikiWord. Even in lowercase.

Who can help with the configure wiki?

```
# uname-a
Linux wiki 3.2.0-24-virtual #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 12:51:49 UTC 2012 
i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

# perl-v

This is a perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for 
i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
(with 56 registered patches, see perl-V for more detail)

# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

# locale-a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.iso88591
ru_RU.iso88595
ru_RU.utf8
ru_UA.utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

[This has been asked on the mailing recently](http://foswiki.2555947.n2.nabble.com/Russian-support-UTF-8-td7577765.html). In short:

international WikiWords don't work, sorry.

In fact I'd argue to disable automatic linking of WikiWords all together using

- Set NOAUTOLINK = on

in your SitePreferences. Instead, use explicit linking using the bracket notation [[...]].

Then use

```
$Foswiki::cfg{UseLocale} = 0; 
$Foswiki::cfg{Site}{LocaleRegexes} = 1; 
$Foswiki::cfg{Ldap}{CharSet} = 'utf-8';
```

If you still would like to enable locales, then remove the -T flag from all perl scripts. 
You can't have both: locales and taintedness checks enabled in perl.

Locales in perl inject a lot of tainted strings coming from the system. As such perl isn't 
able to distinguish strings that rightfully should be considered tainted coming from the user.